# Hover FadeOut for certain class

Tags: jquery, css

I'm working on a navbar on which its an image and there are links there. When the user hover these links it changes the background to the navbar hovered image and specify its place by background-position property of CSS. Now I want to make all links in my website to fade out showing the `.CLASS:hover` image slowly with a jQuery plug in. My code is:

HTML:

```
<div class="navbar"><!-- NavBar Start -->
        <a href="#" class="nav_l_home" title="Home"></a>
        <a href="#" class="nav_l_services" title="Services"></a>
</div><!-- NavBar End -->
```

CSS:

```
.navbar {
    background:url(../img/nav.png) no-repeat;
    width:828px;
    height:72px;
    margin:auto;
    position:relative;
}
a.nav_l_home {
    width:112px;
    height:43px;
    position:absolute;
    bottom:14px;
    right:30px;
}
a.nav_l_home:hover {
    background:url(../img/nav_hov.png) no-repeat;
    background-position: -686px -15px;
}
a.nav_l_services {
    width:107px;
    height:43px;
    position:absolute;
    bottom:14px;
    right:161px;
}
a.nav_l_services:hover {
    background:url(../img/nav_hov.png) no-repeat;
    background-position: -560px -15px;
}
```

mmm sory for the poor explnation ^-^" .. all i want is to make a.nav_l_home:hover background to fade in on mouse hover that's it all ^^

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: I didn't understand this part 'now i want to make all links in my website to fade out showing the .CLASS:hover image slowly', which i guess is your question

Comment: mmm sory for the poor explnation ^-^" .. all i want is to make `a.nav_l_home:hover` background to fade in on mouse hover that's it all ^^"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to make an element fade in and fade out on mouse over / mouse out you can do something like this:

```
$('.foo').hover(

    function() {
        $('#bar').fadeIn();
    },

    function () {
        $('#bar').fadeOut();
    }

);
```

.hover() takes two parameters: the function to call on mouseover and the function to call on mouseout. The methods .fadeIn() and .fadeOut() are self-explanatory. You can adjust the duration of the fade effect by passing the number of milliseconds (integer) as a parameter.